# in_array returning true when item does not exist

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form which allows my user to edit the information as required. As part of this form, the user can insert up to 5 types of proof. All proof is stored in a seperate table:

```
Table: Proof

proofid - primary key
banid - foreign key -> links to banlist table which stores all other information
proof - the link to which contains the proof
type - the type of proof (image, demo, league, ...)
number - the index number of the proof (0 up to 4)
```

I also have the following code to update or insert the item of proof. It loops through each field, and checks if the current selected item in the array is not empty. If true, it checks to see if $i is within the array which stores all the numbers for the selected ban id.

The array looks like this for banid 237: `Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 )`

This in effect says that the first proof field is empty, but the second is not and that a record exists in the table.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $proof = $checkprooflist[$i];
    $prooftype = $checkprooftypelist[$i];

    if (!empty($proof))
    {                       
        if(!in_array($i, $proofnumberlist))
        {
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO proof (banid, proof, type, number) VALUE ($id, '$proof', '$prooftype', $i)";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        }
        else
        {
            $query2 = "UPDATE proof SET proof = '$proof', type = '$prooftype' WHERE number = $i AND banid = $id";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        }
    }           
}
```

The problem I have however is that with the above array, the line `if(!in_array($i, $proofnumberlist))` is returning false and thus not entering the if statement when $i = 0.

It works for all other values (where $i = 1, ...) and so forth but not when $i = 0.

Thank you for reading and I appreciate any help you may be able to give me.

Jon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the other hand, you could sidestep the entire `in_array` check by using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

This would make your code a bit clearer. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Thank you Cory. I shall take a look into this as I didn't actually know such a thing existed!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `$strict` parameter of [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), it's the third one (default = false).

Due to type juggling, an empty string can be equal to 0, etc. The `$strict` parameter makes sure to also test the types.

```
if (!in_array($i, $proofnumberlist, true))
```

Comment: Thank you Jack, though when I set $strict to true, I was faced with several other errors and so changed the nature of the array to only populate with not null values. This new array now works as expected with $strict set to false.

Comment: @JYoung glad to know my code did at least cause you to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no 0 in this array:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 )
```

The element at index 0 is null, not 0. Where did you get this array in the first place?

Comment: The array is populated with values of the rows for the number field. However, when I read your comment I modified this to only insert not null values, so that the array would now read: [0] => 1. This in itself has actually fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. For the record, I like Cory's solution and that is the way I usually handle such queries in my own code.